# Intersection be set and dictionary and intersection of each word in set

Tags: python

The title might sound a little confusing, but what I have is an input of words, for instance:

```
string = "It was"
```

I the turn the string into a list of the two words. Then find when each word intersects with a dictionary, where the words in a text file broken up into lines are the keys and the value is a set of line numbers.

I have this part down no problem, the issue is then finding only when it and was are in the same line. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this.

I am away from my computer at the moment, but if I need to post the code to look over just let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### EDIT

```
def find_cooccurance(D, inp_str):
end_set = set()
words = inp_str.split()
inp_set = set(words)
lst = []

for val in inp_set.intersection(D):
    end_set = D[val]
lst=list(end_set.intersection(D[val]))

if lst == []:
    lst.append("None.")

return sorted(lst)

inp_str = "It was"
```

D = {'it' : {1,2,3}, 'was':{2}}

This is just a small part of the code, the rest of it is very long.

What I have been getting as a return when I print lst:

```
  [1, 2, 3]
```

what I should be seeing is:

```
 [2]
```

Since It and was both appear on that line.

Comment: Your intent is extremely unclear. Can you show us samples of the code you've written, the results you want, and the results you're getting?

Comment: sample of your text file will also be helpful

Comment: Terribly sorry, I made some edits and added code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell what you're looking for without any real example code, but the way I have set it up below, you can find the intersection of all sets of lines corresponding to `'It'` and `'was'` using `lambda` and  `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict
import re

file_text = """
First line
It was a good day :)
Third line
It was a decent day :|
Fifth line
It was a bad day :(
"""

word_dict = defaultdict(set)

for line_no, line in enumerate(file_text.split('\n')):
    for word in re.split('\\s+', line):
        word_dict[word].add(line_no)


def lines_containing_all(*words):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, (word_dict[word] for word in words))

print(lines_containing_all('It', 'was'))
```